# Running Junit on command-Line

Tags: junit, command-line

`initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)` error is coming when `jUnit` code is run on windows command prompt:

Z:\lib\com\example\tests>java -cp Z:\lib\junit-4.12.jar;Z:\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TripPlannerJunit
    JUnit version 4.12.E
    Time: 0
    There was 1 failure:
    1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [TripPlannerJunit]at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TripPlannerJunitat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)... 4 more
    FAILURES!!!
    Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
Edited - . The structure is as follows: 
All the jars are in "Z:\TripPlanner\lib". 
The class and java files are in - "Z:\TripPlanner\lib\com\example\tests"
The package declared is com.example.tests

```
package com.example.tests;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;

public class TripPlannerJUnit {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.com.au/.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testUntitledTestCase() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://transportnsw.info/trip#/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-From")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-From")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-From")).sendKeys("North");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='North Sydney Station'])[1]/following::li[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-To")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-To")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-To")).sendKeys("Town");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Town Hall Station'])[1]/following::ul[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search-button")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out what the problem was. The name of the class in the code was "TripPlannerJunit" while name of the class file was "TripPlannerJUnit" hence the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please, specify the path where your `TripPlannerJunit` is located.

If this is the current folder of a project:

```
java -cp .;Z:\lib\junit-4.12.jar;...
```

or

```
java -cp %CD%;Z:\lib\junit-4.12.jar;...
```

---

**UPDATE** based on clarification in comments.

Assumed you have this structure:

```
Z:\TripPlanner\lib\
|   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
|   junit-4.12.jar
|
+---com
|   \---example
|       \---tests
|               TripPlannerJunit.java
|               TripPlannerJunit.class
```

Run the test from `Z:\TripPlanner\lib` folder:

```
Z:\TripPlanner\lib>java -cp .;junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore "com.example.tests.TripPlannerJunit"
```

Comment: Tried it and it failed too

Comment: Did you compile the project before? By which command? Could you provide the project structure?

Comment: Yes used javac -cp "Z:\TripPlanner\lib\*" Z:\TripPlanner\lib\com\example\tests\TripPlannerJUnit.java

Comment: Could you provide full path of generated `TripPlannerJUnit.class`? What is the package declared there?

Comment: In the original post you mentioned about "Z:\lib", but in the latest comment - "Z:\TripPlanner\lib". Is it the same or different something? Could you provide correct actual paths in both post and comment? It is important to understand your issue.

Comment: Hello @Dymtro Maslenko - My apologies. The structure is as follows: 
All the jars are in "Z:\TripPlanner\lib". 
The class and java files are in - "Z:\TripPlanner\lib\com\example\tests"
Hope that clarifies. 
The package declared is com.example.tests

Comment: Still failing. Z:\TripPlanner\lib>java -cp .;junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore "com.example.tests.TripPlannerJunit"
JUnit version 4.12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/tests/TripPlannerJUnit (wrong name: com/example/tests/TripPlannerJunit)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)

Comment: Please, provide your `TripPlannerJunit.java` class "as is". You can put it in your original post.

Comment: Uploaded in the original post

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out what the problem was. The name of the class in the code was "TripPlannerJUnit" while name of the class file was "TripPlannerJunit" hence the confusion. It is solved now. Thanks for your support